# Integration test locking up on transaction

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, playwright-dotnet

We are creating integration tests using Playwright.
We get a copy of the DB context and

- Begin a transaction
- Set up the data
- Run the test
- Verify the proper action took place
- Rollback the transaction

But the open transaction is preventing the test from completing.

```
public T getContext<T>() where T : DbContext {
    T context = Scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<T>();
    Contexts.Add(context);
    IDbContextTransaction trans = context.Database.BeginTransaction(System.Data.IsolationLevel.ReadUncommitted);            
    Transactions.Add(trans); // remember all transactions so we can roll them back later
    return context;
}
```

The SUT locks up whenever it hits the database.

UPDATE: We are getting back a DbContext, but not the same instance that the SUT is using.
[This page](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/saving/transactions) suggests UseTransaction so we added that to the constructor.

```
public DBContextBase(DbContextOptions options) : base(options) {
    if (transaction != null) {
        Database.UseTransaction(transaction.GetDbTransaction());
    }
}
```

We do see it hit the constructor and use the transaction but it still blocks the second context.

In startup, we try to force the context to use the same instance of the database by

```
builder.Services.AddDbContext<DocumentsContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(new SqlConnection(connection));
});
```

I thought that would work. Still blocking.

Comment: What is the lifetime scope of the service provider for resolving the DbContext? Something like this would only probably work where DbContexts were provided as Transient where things like web services/apps would be using something like PerHttpRequest by default. This code likely won't work if GetRequiredService returns the same instance for integration test runs.  I'd be wary of an approach like this compared to just using a seeded database that can be restored with each run as this is introducing behavior that doesn't exist in production.

Comment: @StevePy Your comment clarified the issue for me. We are getting an instance of the DbContext, but not the *same* instance. So starting a transaction on one instance, blocks the other. I'll extend the question.

Comment: For integration tests it usually works better to use TransactionScope in the test setup, because that leaves the application code unaltered. I wouldn't like this code in `DBContextBase` if it's only there to enable tests.

Comment: @GertArnold Sounds promising but can you expand on your suggestion? I can't see any way to implement this without scattering "using scope" through every context method.

Comment: I realize now that you're talking about end-to-end testing (not integration testing), so that wouldn't work. You're basically accessing the application from the outside. What I said works in integration tests (i.e. "unit tests" against a real database). In our end-to-end tests we always restore a backup for one test run.

Answer (score 0):

There are several methods that claim to let transaction work here. UseTransaction, TransactionScope, etc, but we couldn't get any to work. The database access was blocked until the test timed out then continued, too late.

In the end, we went with snapshots.

```
if (File.Exists("c:\\temp\\snapshots\\snapshot01.snp")) {
   dbContext.Database.ExecuteSql($"DROP DATABASE Snapshot01");
   File.Delete("c:\\temp\\snapshots\\snapshot01.snp");
}
dbContext.Database.ExecuteSql($"CREATE DATABASE Snapshot01 ON(NAME={databasename}, FILENAME= 'c:\\temp\\snapshots\\snapshot01.snp') AS SNAPSHOT OF {databasename}");
----
context.Database.ExecuteSql($"USE MASTER; ALTER DATABASE {databasename} SET Single_User WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE");
context.Database.ExecuteSql($"USE MASTER; RESTORE DATABASE {databasename} FROM DATABASE_SNAPSHOT = 'Snapshot01'");
context.Database.ExecuteSql($"USE MASTER; ALTER DATABASE {databasename} SET Multi_User");
```